# Start QT Application on bootup on an Embedded Linux Device (Beaglebone Black)

Tags: linux, embedded, qt

Below is picture of the display on bootup. Expected display is overwritten by Angstrom screen

[image]

Expected Display

[image]

Application is been started as a service. Below is the content of the service file

```
[Unit]
Description=QTAccelerometer GUI
After=systemd-user-sessions.service

[Service]
WorkingDirectory=/home/root/projects/qt-projects
ExecStart=/home/root/projects/qt-projects/QTAccelerometer -qws
SyslogIdentifier=QTAccelerometer
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5

[Install]
Alias=display-manager.service
```

Below are the other options tried without success

```
[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
WantedBy=graphical.target
```

The system sometimes boots up as expected. When the issue occurs the expected screen splashes followed by the Angstrom screen. Then the dynamic widget update the screen but the static information is not visible.

Any thoughts as to how to fix this issue?

---

**References**

- [Creating Ångström System Services on BeagleBone Black](http://mattrichardson.com/BeagleBone-System-Services/)
- [What Is Systemd and How It Works (Part 1)](http://ktaraghi.blogspot.com/2013/11/what-is-systemd-and-how-it-works-part-1.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
[Unit]
After=getty@.service or getty.target

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Also consider removing the following from the service file

```
After=systemd-user-sessions.service
Alias=display-manager.service
```